# Парсинг сайтов python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, web-scraping

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какие-нибудь инструменты для парсинга сайта https://eospark.com/tokens. Просто с помощью beautifulsoup не получается парсить так как код страница написан коряво. Мне необходимо получить все сайты и имена с 245 страниц этого сайта. С помощью каких инструментов (не обязательно python, но желательно) это можно сделать?

Comment: Код страницы явно генерится "на лету", поэтому нужно использовать Selenium или другой какой-то движок, полноценно эмулирующий браузер и умеющий выполнять JavaScript.

Comment: Самое удобное -- `selenium` или его аналоги, например QWebEngine из модуля pyqt5, как-то делал на нем инжект jquery и авто авторизацию на гитхабе: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/6e7148fc5ea37513749cd4376d08c1a3022efa0d/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/QWebEngine__fill_form_login__auth__github_com/main.py еще попробуйте https://github.com/psf/requests-html, по описанию проекта, там есть встроенный js-движок